# Find a vector function that represents the curve of intersection of two surfaces and the tangent vector

Tags: vectors, surfaces, curves

Consider the curve $C$ obtained by intersecting the surfaces defined by
$$x^2+y^2 + z^2=3$$ and $$x^2-y^2+z^2 =1$$
At the point $(1,1,1)$, which of the following is a tangent vector to the curve?

The answer to this question is $(2, 0, -2)$ , but I don't understand why that is the case. I've tried finding the curve to the two surfaces, but I don't know how to properly do so in this case because I end up with $\pm$ square roots and I'm not sure you need to find it in this case.

I know how to find the tangent vector given a vector equation, just take the derivative and substitute in the point, but I'm missing the vector equation.

Comment: Your curve in spherical coordinates is $\sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the suggestion, I would like to say yes, but I'm still kind of confused at what either answer is trying to say. I get it a little bit and it seems on the way to an answer. As in are you saying, take the gradient of each, substitute the point (1,1,1) and then cross product them? I tried that and got (8, 0, -8) which looks very similar to (2, 0, -2), but what I don't understand is, is it mathematically sound just to take out a factor of 4 and why? It's so close that I'd say it has to be, is it because it is asking for a tangent vector?

Comment: @zkutch is there any way to convert that into a vector equation or to take the derivative of it easily? Apologies never really heard of spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $df(x)/dx$ gives you a slope at $x$ for the function $f(x)$. Along the same lines the gradient of $f(x,y,z)$ will give you the "equivalent to the slope but in higher dimensions". The gradient of your first curve is the vector $(2x 2y 2z)^T$, where $T$ means transpose. The other is computed analogously. Since you have the point of intersection $P=(1,1,1)$, by replacing the coordinates of $P$ into the vectors determined via the gradient you will  get 2 vectors (not necessarily parallel). The tangent you are looking for is perpendicular to the two tangents to the curves, so the cross product will lead to a vector pointing in the direction you are looking for up to a multiplicative constant (for example, if you remove the 2 in the gradient vectors and operate you will get a different vector, but the direction is the same).

Comment: Okay so you're saying find the gradient of both separately and then cross product them as the common tangent to both would be perpendicular to them which gets me (8, 0, -8) and yep it makes sense that you can take out a factor of a scalar, because it still points in the same direction so the answer could be (2, 0 , -2) but taking out a factor of 4. The one question I'm a little confused about is why do you need the transpose of the gradient?

Comment: @ John Smith The transpose is not needed, but it is a common practice in "engineering settings" to write the vectors in column form. You can safely neglect that.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to determine the intersection curve.

By subtracting the equations you get $y=\pm 1$.

By adding the equations you get $x^2+z^2=2$.

Therefore the intersection curve is made by two circles located on two planes parallel to XOZ, one given by equation y=-1 and the other by y=1.

Now moving to point of construction: [1,1,1] is located on one of the two circles.

The intersection curve is:
$
\vec{p}(t)= \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc} \sqrt2 \cdot cos (t) &s & \sqrt2 \cdot sin(t) \end{array} }\right], t\epsilon [0, 2\pi), s=\pm1$;

If $t=\frac{\pi}{4}, s=1, $ then the point [1, 1, 1] is obtained.

Now to determine the tangent vector, is enough to differentiate the position vector:

$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}(\frac{\pi}{4})= \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc} -1&0 & 1 \end{array} }\right]$

Next I would normalize the vector to $ \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} &0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \end{array} }\right]$

Note: this vector is not identical to the one you provided as answer. Is opposite in direction and has a length 1.